# How to avoid duplication when entering a value into a data validation cell, which allows multiple selection

Tags: vba, excel

There are certain columns in my database, that requires me to type in new data as well as make selections. So, I made a drop down list through data validation. I can select multiple selections according to the code, but if I keyed in any data into that cell, the original selection will show up twice.

Eg. Cell contains the choices: ABC, XYZ
I chose ABC, typed in WWW
The cell will then show ABC, ABC, WWW

Anyone can help prevent the duplication of the original choice?

Here is the code I currently have, I tried to remove the "oldVal" part to prevent duplication, it prevented me from choosing multiple choices.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim lUsed As Long
    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo exitHandler
    If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler
    If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
         'do nothing
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newVal = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldVal = Target.Value
        Target.Value = newVal
        If Target.Column = 28 Or Target.Column = 29 Or Target.Column = 30 Then
            If oldVal = "" Then
                 'do nothing
            Else
                If newVal = "" Then
                     'do nothing
                Else
                    lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
                    If lUsed > 0 Then
                        If oldVal = newVal Then
                            Target.Value = ""
                        ElseIf Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                            Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) - Len(newVal) - 1)
                        Else
                            Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal & vbLf, "")
                        End If
                    Else
                        Target.Value = oldVal & vbLf & newVal
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting code. FYI it works fine for me. When I select ABC, and then type WWW, it shows ABC - WWW. When I type WWW again, it is removed. Same thing happens if I select ABC. Nothing is wrong with the code.

Comment: WWW is not meant to be in the dropdown list, if you have added WWW into the dropdown list then it works fine.

Comment: No not in the list, I got that. Maybe you can open a new worksheet, copy this code and create a data validation and check again, do you have any other code in your worksheet?

Comment: Yes I have just tried it on a different workbook, and it works fine, but it doesn't have multi select, like now I can't choose ABC and XYZ to appear in the same cell. /// And no I dont have any other codes in that worksheet, but I have codes in modules.

Comment: I checked your code line by line and there is no logical error. Also there is no duplicates and whatever I select/enter is added to list. Typing again removed them as well.

Comment: I just tried again on a different workbook and it still duplicates my original selection. T-T

Comment: I really don't have any issue. But there is only one problem with your code.   After selecting ABC, if you type BC, the ABC is gone because of using `InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)`

Comment: Oh I see.. anyway thank you for your help, I'll see what I can do T-T